# How to best position a dehumidifier

Tags: air-conditioning, dehumidifier, placement

Want to ask about the best orientation for a portable dehumidifier to allow cloths to dry the quickest. Take this top down drawing of a portable dehumidifier as an example:

[image]

Air inlets are at the two sides of the back and warmed air blows out from the front at an angle.

Would it be quicker if the warmed air is blowing directly towards the cloth rack, so that the accelerated and warmed air draws the moist within the cloths directly. Or position the air inlets facing the cloth rack as close as possible so that humid air is easier to be sucked in?

The difference may be tiny if both the dehumidifier and the cloth rack are placed in a small room. So consider both are freely movable within a big room, what is the best positions and orientations of them both?

Comment: use a fan to blow air at the rack ... that moves humid air away from the clothes and promotes faster drying

Comment: @jsotola you mean the fan of the dehumidifier?

Comment: any fan, as long as it disturbs the air around the clothes

Comment: Yes, the question is not about drying clothes (otherwise you can say put them in a dryer), its about the best orientation to position a dehumidifier if it is used to dry clothes.

Comment: The answer still is "don't."  It's 100X more efficient to use a regular fan to move air past the clothes.  This is not what a dehumidifier is designed to do, and unless the room air itself is humid, there won't be much heating going on in the first place.